# JWT - High quality ways to handle the user experience of a returning logged in user

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, authentication, user-experience

I have a client that, once authenticated, stores a JWT in `localStorage`.  If a user closes the browser, and once again navigates to the site, the client first checks for the JWT in `localStorage`, and if present, redirects via:

```
window.location.href = `/?jwt=${token}`
```

This works fine except I'm not a fan of the user experience. The user visits a page, is shown a login page, and then it abruptly redirects to a new page.

I have played around with hiding `/auth/login`'s UI if a JWT token is found, but it's still not great.

What are some better ways to handle the case where a user has left a site, comes back and should be logged in?

**Is there a way for a user to return to a site after having closed their browser, and immediately be shown as logged in using JWT's?**

Comment: Have you checked out [react-router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router)? And what do you mean with "the client first checks for the JWT"? Where does it check?

Comment: Yes, I've used `react-router`.  The client checks for the JWT in `localStorage` because once authenticated, the client stores the JWT returned from the server in `localStorage`.  The problem is that the server needs the JWT to know if a client should or should not be logged in, and the JWT is stored on the client.  So, I need to load a client and _then_ send this JWT to the server, which is why the client get's redirected instead of being shown as logged in on first page load.

Comment: why don't you first show the index and if the user doesn't have a token, redirect to the login? The other way around, makes sense for non-logged users, cleaner for logged users

Comment: @yBrodsky, That's a great idea.  The reason I did it this way was to be able to prevent non-logged in users from being able to request static assets like images, videos, PDFs, etc.  The way I did that was to trust any requests from a certain `req.referer`.

Comment: Well, even if you have it like this. If I have the url I can request the assets. You could serve the assets through some auth protected url: /assets/images/image.png => returns image.png Though that would put more load in your app.

Comment: I have some middleware that protects assets and will only serve them if they have been requested from a certain `referer`.  If you are not logged in, you won't be able to request the assets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post does a great job of answering the question:

https://dev.to/rtfeldman/defense-against-the-dark-arts-csrf-attacks